# How openly should I advertise my packages and prices?

Tags: business, pricing

In terms of advertising, how upfront do you advertise and display your rates and prices? A lot of photographers don't have their packages or rates on their websites and you have to inquire to receive them via email. I'm currently in the process of printing new flyers and my packages are advertised on the reverse side. I'm unsure if this is a negative thing. What should I consider?

Answer (score 3):

Some photographers charge different rates for the same products depending on the type of photography (wedding vs. sports vs. school, for example), mostly due to the amount of backend work needed to produce product up to the customer's standards.  Other photographers charge the same price for products, but charge different rates for the shoot itself ($20,000 for a high-end wedding shoot vs. free for a sports league or school shoot, since there's probably going to be a lot more prints ordered from a sports shoot, for example).  Some do a combination of the two -- various rates for shooting and for products.

Do what makes sense for how you run your business.  If you always charge the same rate for products regardless of the situation, why not put your prices on your brochure?  It makes you up front about your business, and eliminates customers who aren't willing to pay your rates, rather than you having to do extra work explaining pricing to people who end up not being your customers after all.  If you want to be more flexible with your rates, don't list your prices, and look forward to spending more time communicating with potential customers.